# Dynamic Report link shows all records and filtered records

Tags: reporting

I want to build a button on a visualforce page that takes the user to a report. The vf page has 5 filters that a user can choose from. I can pass the value in the filter to the report using pv0={}&pv1={}... ect.

[image]

[image]

My problem is this only works if they fill out every filter then click the button. I've only ever used one filter before by passing in the Opportunityid. Is there a way to say if there is a filter use it else show all the records? Or if only one filter is used use that and ignore the other filters?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but dashboards allow you to display charts or tables and allow you to modify the filters on those charts/tables as well as allow you to go to the source data (report) and drill down in those reports. Is there a reason you're not using a dashboard? Alternatively a report is just a fancy UI tossed on top of a DB query. You could go the way of building your own dynamic query and displaying a table of data without going to a report at all.

Comment: The users will only access and modify the records in the vf page, It has a big table that they can edit values under the filters. We gave them a link to a report in case they wanted to export it or do other reporting actions that they could not do in the page.

In that sense it's not really a dashboard that I'm working with.

Comment: It is very possible to create a VF page that can take a query and turn it into a CSV file for download which could solve at least one of those problems.

Comment: I did not think of that, so instead of pushing them to a standard report just give them the file that they would have pulled from the report anyway.

Comment: Right I was looking because I know I've seen information on rendering VF pages as CSV files in this forum. If you go digging I'm sure you can find what you need.